# Justify text in Android

Tags: android, textview, text-justify

How to Justify paragraph in textview setText option? I am loading data from API and need to display paragraph as justified.

textv.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
I have tried  below in adapter but nothing works
text = text + ""+paragrph +"

";

Is it possible other than webview ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the property like gravity in TextView. You can either use WebView or other open source libraries.
Android does not support text justification yet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use WebView to justify text. Here is it an example:

```
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView .setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    String header = "<html><head><style type=\"text/css\">@font-face {font-family: MyFont;src: url(\"file:///android_asset/fonts/Walkway-Ultrabold.ttf\")}body {font-family: MyFont;font-size: medium;text-align: justify;}</style></head><body>";
    String footer = "</body></html>";
    String text_web_view = header + message + footer;
    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, text_web_view, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

This code set also a font placed into assets/fonts folder.

Comment: I don't want to webview